# Show mongoose aggregation result as one object

Tags: mongoose, aggregation

I want to show the aggregation result as one object, like:

```
{
  ...
}
```

instead of

```
[
  {
   ...
  }
]
```

like the findOne query.

Is there a way to make that possible?

Thanks!

Comment: By default `Aggregate` returns an array, there is no way you can return the object from Aggregate. See this answer.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52330801/mongoose-return-a-single-document-instead-of-an-array-of-documents-with-aggreg

Comment: Could you please share a few sample documents and your aggregation pipeline? Depending on the nesting of your results, you may be able to convert an array to an object with [$unwind](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/) or [$arrayToObject](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/arrayToObject).